# Why does this minimization with parameters does not work?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, assumptions

This statement:

```
Simplify[Minimize[{Exp[3 q], q >= 0}, q]]
```

Returns correctly:

```
{1, {q -> 0}}
```

But this statement:

```
Assuming[n > 1, Simplify[Minimize[{Exp[n q], q >= 0}, q]]]
```

returns:

```
Minimize[{E^(n q), True}, q]
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is Mathematica just unable to handle the extra parameter?

Comment: Set `n` also as the target variable of `Minimize`: `Minimize[{Exp[n q], q >= 0, n >1}, {q, n}]`.

Comment: @AlexanderZeng this gives a specific value for $n$:  {1, {q -> 0, n -> 2}}. But the minimization of $q$ is actually true for every $n>0$...