# Parametric Minimize strongly revisited

Tags: mathematical-optimization, core-language

Let we try to run this simple code:

```
Minimize[{Cos[x + a/2], {0 <= x <= \[Pi], 0 < a < 1}}, x]
```

It doesn't work. But

```
Minimize[{(x + a)^2, {0 <= x <= 1, 0 < a < 1}}, x]
```

works fine, *with parametric output for any suitable parameter*!
I’ve read 3-4 answers like these: [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164738/why-does-this-minimization-with-parameters-does-not-work)  [[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272472/mathematica-failing-to-minimize-with-parameters)
They suggest add `a` to variables of minimization:

```
Minimize[{Cos[a/2 + x], {0 <= x <= \[Pi], 0 < a < 1}}, {a, x}]
Output:{-1, {a -> 9/34, x -> 1/68 (-9 + 68 \[Pi])}}
```

But this is kinda cheating, 'cause we need fully parametric solution,
as for example with `a x^2 + b x + x` in documentation.
And we can get it, e.g.:

```
Reduce[D[Cos[a/2 + x], x] == 0 && D[Cos[a/2 + x], {x, 2}] > 0 && 
  0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi], x, Reals]
Out: C[1] \[Element] Integers && -2 \[Pi] + 4 \[Pi] C[1] <= a <= 
  2 \[Pi] + 4 \[Pi] C[1] && x == 1/2 (-a + 2 \[Pi] + 4 \[Pi] C[1])
```

So whats wrong with `Minimize`?

Comment: `Solve[{D[Cos[x + a/2], x] == 0, 0 <= x <= \[Pi], 0 < a < 1}, x]` ? `{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-a + 2 \[Pi]), 0 < a < 1]}`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci, yes, but my goal is not to get partial result in any way, but figure out what’s wrong with `Minimize`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: You consider only the necessary condition of a local minimum of a diffirentiable function which is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

`Minimize/Maximize` handles  expressions with polynomials much better than expressions with transcendental functions. I'd like to quote the documentation

> If `f` and `cons` are linear or polynomial, `Minimize` will always find a global minimum

This explains the difference between `{Cos[x + a/2]` and `(x + a)^2` in your examples.
Because of this reason we apply `TrigExpand[Cos[x + a/2]]` and then consider a linear target function and polynomial constraints (The notations are clear.)

```
Minimize[{Cos[a/2] cx - Sin[a/2]  sx, 
0 < a < 1 && cx^2 + sx^2 == 1}, {cx, sx}] // FullSimplify
```

> $$ \left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & 0<a<1 \\
>  \infty  & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> ,\left\{\text{cx}\to 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & \sin \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)=0\land \cos \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)<0\land 0<a<1 \\
>  -\cos \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) & 0<a<1 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> ,\text{sx}\to 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & \sin \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)=0\land \cos \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)=0\land 0<a<1 \\
>  \sin \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) & 0<a<1 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right.\right.$$

At last, for the non-degenerate case

```
Reduce[Cos[x] == -Cos[a/2] && Sin[x] == Sin[a/2] && 0 < a && a < 1 &&  x >= 0 && x <= Pi, x, Reals]
```

> `0 < a < 1 && x == 2 ArcTan[Cot[a/4]]`

Comment: BTW,`Minimize[{Cos[x + a/2], 
  0 <= x <= \[Pi] && 0 <= a <= 1 && 
   Reduce[D[Cos[x + a/2], x] == 0 && D[Cos[x + a/2], {x, 2}] > 0&& 0 <= x <= \[Pi] && 0 <= a <= 1, x]},
  x]` returns the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, a_] := Cos[x + a/2]

cons = {0 <= x <= π, 0 < a < 1};

cond = Assuming[cons,
  Reduce[{D[f[x, a], x] == 0, D[f[x, a], {x, 2}] > 0, cons} // 
     Flatten, x] // Simplify]

(* a + 2 x == 2 π *)

min = Simplify[f[x, a], cond]

(* -1 *)
```

Comment: The command `Minimize[{RealAbs[Cos[a/2]  cx - Sin[a/2]   sx], 
   0 < a < 1 && cx^2 + sx^2 == 1}, {cx, sx}] // FullSimplify` works whereas the approach suggested by you doesn't.